# Логика работы итератора ArrayList

Tags: java, итераторы

Не могу уложить в голове логику работы итераторов. Вот, например, такая программа:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RememberingJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add("0");
        numbers.add("1");
        numbers.add("2");

        ListIterator<String> iterator = numbers.listIterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
        System.out.println();

        iterator.set("111");
        while (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.previous());
        }
    }
}
```

Что происходит после заполнения списка?

По моей логике: создается итератор, который указывает на элемент "0". Затем, т.к. после "0" есть "1", то выводится "0", и итератор переходит на "1". После "1" есть "2", поэтому выводится "1", и итератор переходит на "2". Но после "2" ничего нет.

Вопрос - почему "2" выводится, и почему после вывода "2" итератор остается на нем же (судя по тому, что элементу, хранящему "2" нормально присваивается "111", итератор ведь остался на "2")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первоначально итератор ни на что не указывает, он как бы указывает на место перед первым элементом списка. Если в этот момент у итератора вызвать метод `next()`, а при этом список пуст, то возникнет исключение `Exceptionjava.util.NoSuchElementException`. Если предварительно вызвать `hasNext()`, то последний вернет `false`, таким образом, конструкция

```
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```

будет правильно работать независимо от того, есть что-то в списке или нет -- в случае пустого цикла тело просто не выполнится ни разу, поскольку условие цикла (`iterator.hasNext()`) с самого начала будет `false`.

Далее, если список содержит хоть один элемент, метод `iterator.hasNext()` вернет `true`. Смысл этого метода точно определяется его названием -- в буквальном переводе оно значит "Есть еще один". Этот метод мы можем вызывать сколько угодно, состояние итератора от него не меняется -- итератор по-прежнему указывает на "место перед первым". При этом первый (т.е. нулевой, с индексом 0) элемент списка являются следующим по отношению к текущей позиции итератора, так что метод `next()` вернет этот "следующий" (нулевой) элемент. Метод `next()`, в отличие от метода `hasNext()`, меняет состояние итератора -- сдвигает его на одну позицию, так что после этого `hasNext()` будет сообщать, есть ли в списке второй элемент(т.е. опять следующий по отношению к прочитанному), а следующий вызов `next()` вернет этот второй элемент и опять изменит позицию итератора. Если прочитанный элемент -- это последний элемент списка, то `hasNext()` после этого вернет `false`, и наш цикл не сможет продолжать работу.

После чтения элемента "2" в вашем примере итератор продолжает указывать на него, поскольку после его чтения вы больше не вызывали `next()` (а если бы вызвали, то получили бы исключение, т. к. следующего за ним элемента нет). Поэтому,  действительно, вызов `iterator.set("111")` заменяет последний элемент списка ссылкой на новую строку "111". Так и должно быть -- документация учит, что

> void set(E e) -- Replaces the last element returned by next() or previous() with the specified element (optional operation).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Метод `listIterator` создаёт новый итератор, поле `cursor` которого равен нулю
2. Метод `hasNext` сравнивает текущее значение `cursor` с количеством элементов в списке. Если они не совпадают, метод возвращает `true`
3. Метод `next` возвращает элемент с индексом `cursor` и увеличивает значение `cursor` на единицу. Также в методе запоминается индекс возвращённого элемента в поле `lastRet`

В итоге после первого цикла `cursor` равняется 3, а `lastRet` равен 2

Метод `set` использует `lastRet`, а не `cursor`, поэтому изменяется именно третий элемент списка

1. Метод `hasPrevious` сравнивает `cursor` с нулём. Если не равен - возвращается `true`
2. Метод `previous` возвращает элемент с индексом `cursor - 1` и уменьшает значение `cursor` на единицу. Также в методе запоминается индекс возвращённого элемента в поле `lastRet`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле при создании итератора он не указывает на первый элемент коллекции, он лишь знает, что при первом вызове метода next() он будет указывать на первый элемент, если таковой имеется. Другими словами итератор как бы находится в неопределённом состоянии до первого вызова next(). Ну и логика его действий будет такова:

```
iterator = numbers.listIterator(); // положение итератора не определёно
 // 1-й цикл
iterator.hasNext() // true
iterator.next()) // 0
 // 2-й цикл
iterator.hasNext() // true
iterator.next()) // 1
 // 3-й цикл
iterator.hasNext() // true
iterator.next()) // 2
 // 4-й цикл
iterator.hasNext() // false
```

после чего итератор находится на последнем элементе.

Answer (score 1):

1. Создается итератор, который находится перед первым элементом
2. после итератора что-то есть, т.е. "0" - итератор передвигается на него и выводит "0"
3. после "0" что-то есть - итератор передвигается на "1" и выводит "1"
4. после "1" что-то есть - итератор передвигается на "2" и выводит "2"
5. выводится пустая строка
6. элементу, на котором стоит итератор, т.е. "2" устанавливается значение "111"
7. перед "111" что-то есть - выводим "111" и смещаем итератор на "1"
8. перед "1" что-то есть - выводим "1" и смещаем итератор на "0"
9. перед "0" лежит начало итератора - выводим "0" и смещаем итератор в начало.

---

**ИТОГО:** Вверх и вниз итератор двигается по-разному:

- при движении вверх сначала поднимается итератор, затем выводится текущий элемент.
- при движении вниз сначала выводится текущий элемент, затем опускается итератор.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ :)